# Nested double each() and $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I have two arrays: `menu_items` and `clones`, and I have two nested each() functions.

```
$(menu_items).each(function() {
  $(clones).each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == ...) {
        <do sth>
    }
  });
});
```

I want to check if `href` from item from second loop (clones) is equal to `href` from item from first loop (menu_items).
Checking items from `clones` is easy: `$(this).attr("href")`. But what with first loop `menu_items`? `$(this).$(this).attr("href")`? I guess not :( Please help.

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid `this` problems and use the second `each` parameter instead, it'll make the code more readable too

Comment: @CertainPerformance To avoid confusion: you are talking about js `.forEach` which has a scope/this parameter, OP uses jquery `.each` which does not have that.

Comment: @Xatenev Sure it does, he just needs to define the variables as the 2nd arguments. See https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Xatenev `$(clones).each(function(_, clone) {` results in `clone` being one of the `clones`, no need for `this` at all, same thing with the outer loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the `this` reference in the outer loop to use it in the inner:

```
$(menu_items).each(function() {
  const outerThis = $(this);

  $(clones).each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == outerThis.attr('href')) {
        <do sth>
    }
  });
});
```

alternatively use the 2nd param of `.each` as described by CertainPerformance:

```
 $(menu_items).each(function(_, menuItem) {

      $(clones).each(function(_, clone) {
        if (clone.attr("href") == menuItem.attr('href')) {
            <do sth>
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed :)

Comment: @sailormoon see update, use whatever you prefer.

Comment: It's also awesome solution, thanks!